# Return textfile as multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, database, multidimensional-array, document-storage

Hope everything is good.

I use php file() and it works very well. I only need to separate my "values" in the txt-file with a new row, and then 'file()' will give me the contents of the txt-file as an array with all the values separately.

I do not know if I can take the same function one step further to achieve 'key/values' and '**multidimensional arrays**'. If not, what do I have for other options to be able to save 'text data' in a txt file and then get it back in a multidimensional array?

At the moment, I only get the following:

```
[0] => 'value1',
[1] => 'value2',
[2] => 'value3',
```

If you know any solutions that are very straightforward and can put me on the right track here, I am very grateful.

Comment: You may be better off using JSON formatted files.

Comment: Hey @NigelRen , thanks for the tip. Can I save the JSON strings in text documents and separate the objects with a line break? Ex.:

{"name": "John", "age": 31, "city": "New York"}

{"name": "Marley", "age": 22, "city": "Miami"};

and then use file () and manage the strings in php?

Or do you usually do something else that is more straightforward in this case?

Comment: `file_put_contents()` and `file_get_contents()` is the most direct when storing and retrieving json strings to `json_encode` `json_decode` with. In short, you really don't want to mess with the json. Do not format it, do not alter it. Just store it as is, and retrieve it as is.

Comment: @IncredibleHat , file_get_contents returns the content + the number '1' :S

Comment: "*file_get_contents returns the content + the number 1*" ... no, [it does not](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). Without seeing the code, I cannot offer much else why you get more than what it actually returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple primer for doing this with JSON:

```
// example array of data
$myarray = array();
$myarray[] = ['name' => 'value 1','age' => '31','city' => 'nowhere'];
$myarray[] = ['name' => 'value 2','age' => '12','city' => 'somewhere'];
$myarray[] = ['name' => 'value 3','age' => '67','city' => 'anywhere'];
print_r($myarray);

// to save your array to a file
file_put_contents('/path/to/file.json',json_encode($myarray));

// now to retrieve:
$myarray = json_decode(file_get_contents('/path/to/file.json'),true);
print_r($myarray);
```

By doing it this way, you retain those keys you want, and the values. The JSON encoding/decoding handles all the painful bits of storing it as text in a flatfile.

Comment: Do you think it is better/safer/faster to use json_decode/json_encode to get the content in and out from text instead of serialize / unserialize? Or is it about the same thing?

Comment: It is better to use json in your case, because it will create a much smaller file, and be quick. If you are storing whole php class objects, or functionality, then `serialize` will be good.